# completion in shell mode does not handle + in filenames for ls, does for cd

Tags: emacs

I have a file at location `/tmp/z+b/c`

In a shell buffer, if I type at the prompt `cd /tmp/z<TAB>` and press then completion changes it to `cd /tmp/z+b/`, because that is the only entry starting with `z`.

The same thing happens if I type start with `ls /tmp/z<TAB>`, the text changes to `ls /tmp/z+b/`.

But another `<TAB>` results in different behavior:

- For `cd`, the text changes to `cd /tmp/z+b/c/`, again because `c` is the only entry in that directory.
- But for `ls`, the minibuffer reports `no match`. I captured the screenshot below immediately after the message was displayed.

  [image]

If I instead type `ls /tmp/z+<TAB>` then neither does completion occur nor is any message displayed in minibuffer. So it seems completion does not handle `+` character correctly.

**Update**

Running Cygwin 32 bit Emacs version 24.3.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Consider doing `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I can't duplicate this on Emacs 24.3.50.1 on Linux. What OS and Emacs version are you using?

Comment: @Tyler I had suspected it may be specific to Cygwin build but forgot to mention that. Thanks for verifying.